# Item doesn't get removed from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking for hours atm but I can't seem to delete an item from my database. The `$id` is from `$_GET['id']`

```
<?php


$hostdb = "localhost";
$userdb = "root";
$pwdb = "";
$namedb = "cloud";

$dbCon = mysqli_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $pwdb, $namedb);

if(!$dbCon){
    die("CONNECTION FAILED");
}

?>
```

Call to action remove button. Redirect to `customers.php`

```
<form action="customers.php" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="remove" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i> Remove</button>
</form>

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['remove'])) { 
                include("php/remove.php");
                removeCustomer($id);
            } 
            ?>
```

Remove class

```
<?php
function removeCustomer($id){


    include("connect.php");

    $query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE Id='$id'";

echo $id //gives me the right id

    if(!mysqli_query($dbCon,$query) === TRUE){
        echo "Error while removing customer from the database.";
    }

    mysqli_close($dbCon);
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
When I redirect to the same page, then it does get removed. 
But that's not the right way I suppose.

Ex. When I'm at page `customer.php?id=2` and my form redirects to `customer.php?id=2` then it's removed.

**UPDATE 2 + SOLUTION**
I've removed the "action" redirect in my form and it works fine.

Comment: The name of your id field is capitalized?

Comment: so you can see your echo `echo "Error while removing customer from the database.";` when trying to call the page?

Comment: Use `if(!$dbCon->query($query)) die('Error while removing customer from the database: [' . $db->error . ']');` to execute the query and tell us the error message.

Comment: @bobdye It's "Id" in my database, so the sql query should be fine

Comment: @Alex I don't see that error. I redirect to the customers page and when I remove I'm at customer.php?id=19 (depending on the id)

Comment: We need more information here; for instance, what _are_ you seeing? What are the results? What is being output, what is happening in the database? We're only seeing the setup here, so we can't help you without knowing what's actually happening.

Comment: @treegarden What is my $result variable then?

Comment: @AlecDeitloff Did you downvote me for that? I posted as much as I could. What do I see? Well, I get redirected like I said. What's happening in the database? Well nothing because like my title said: It doesn't get removed. I don't get any error. I've inserted the query in my database and that worked fine.

Comment: Why are you talking about GET parameters, while your form is POST? Are you sure you are getting the id submitted correctly?

Comment: @KaiMattern Yes, I added an echo of my id in the remove class and I got the right id. The `$_GET['id']` is from my link query `customer.php?id=25`

Comment: But it will not be included in the POST of the form. Mixing http methods is a bad practice. You should grab the id from the get and put it into a hidden field into your form. Then you can grab the id from the POST parameters in a clean way. And the function would also work if reused on other pages.

Comment: @OllieJones But I doubt it's failing because when I put the query in my database manually everything works just fine

Comment: Try it  `$query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE Id=$id"; ` without single quote in $id

Comment: @BeingSunny Changed it but it still doesn't delete it.

Comment: I've added a solution(?) that seemed to work for me, not sure if this is the right way to do.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do to tighten up this code and make it more self-diagnostic when it goes wrong.

First, follow the convention on handling the result from `mysqli_query()`. Just check for the negation.

Secondly, make your error message announce the problem as well as the failure. Also, for troubleshooting's sake, make it announce success.

Thirdly, it's unlikely but possible that you don't have autocommit set. So commit your change immediately after you do the delete.

That will produce this code.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE Id='$id'";

if(!mysqli_query($dbCon,$query)){
    echo "Error while removing customer ($id) from the database: " 
               . $dbCon->error;
}
else {
    echo "Customer ($id) correctly removed from the database.";
}
if (!mysqli_commit($dbCon)) {
    echo "Transaction commit failed: " . $dbCon->error;
}

mysqli_close($dbCon);
```

Finally, use a bind parameter to protect your code against cybercriminals. Then your code will look like this.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE Id=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbCon, $query) || die ($dbCon->error);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'd', $id) || die ($dbCon->error);


if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo "Error while removing customer ($id) from the database: " 
               . $dbCon->error;
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

if (!mysqli_commit($dbCon)) {
    echo "Transaction commit failed: " . $dbCon->error;
}

mysqli_close($dbCon);
```

This business with the $stmt looks like a lot of extra work. But it's *much* safer -- proof against malicious rubbish in your $id variable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your If condition with this code.

```
if(mysqli_query($dbCon,$query) == FALSE){
    echo "Error while removing customer from the database.";
}
```

OR

```
if(mysqli_query($dbCon,$query) != TRUE){
    echo "Error while removing customer from the database.";
}
```

AND

if your Id is int then remove single quote in where condition.

Comment: The code I have works just fine, the problem is that I don't get the error. So there's no problem connecting to the database, nor is the query wrong